# Mongoose Update operation ObjectId Cast Error on New Ref

Tags: mongoose

I have an issue where if I try save a new ref property to an existing document I get an castId error, however this same update works fine IF I had originally created that document with that document property set.

Let me try to explain a bit more:

I have a schema like so:

```
name: String,
desc: String,
user: {
  type: ObjectId,
 ref: 'User'
}
```

Now if I create a new document with the 'user' value set, I can freely update that. However if I create the document without a 'user' value and then later try to update it with user value I get a

'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]"'

The data I send back to my function is same in both cases, which is a JSON object that has an '_id' field.

When I first create it, all I do is set 'user' to a objectID value myself, but after that I can send a JSON object with a _id and it works fine for updates (if the value was already set on creation).

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to do this? My update code is quite simple:

```
myModel = _.extend(myModel, req.body);
myModel.save()
```

My create code when I first add the document is also simple:

```
var model = new Model(req.body);
model.save()
```

I can fix this by setting the req.body.user to an '_id' before running the _.extend operation only when it does not already exist. It is not ideal and feels a bit hacky but I guess it works.

However this becomes even more troublesome when I have the same error when dealing with an array of embedded objects which contains a ref... Now surely instead of checking on every update operation is there is a new item on the array, convert all 'Ref' properties to ObjectId manually....

Can't mongoose automatically detect the '_id' field, grab it and store that as a reference? 
Why does this work fine when this field was originally set on document creation?

So if it was set on creation, then even if send the whole JSON object, it only happens when I try to add a new field or new array entry (that contains an object with a ref) that I get this error.

To show what I mean by an embedded array doc with ref:

```
{
myProp: String,
myDetails: [{
  name: String,
  myUser: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
}]
```

I hope I made sense here? If not please let me know if there is anything confusing.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I have something very similar.

Comment: I did, I'll put an answer in.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason this happens is due to expecting a type of 'ObjectId'. This generally doesn't happen if you create a new Mongoose model and assign that to a 'ref' field than mongoose is clever enough to recognise it and just extract the 'ObjectId' from it.

So two ways:

1) Do it manually yourself:

MyModel.refField = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(myString)

2) Get the model and assign it:

var myModel = MyModel.findById(myString);
MyModel.refFeild = myModel;